# Test that the client channel receives a message

Tags: websocket, elixir, integration-testing, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix application, I have a channel that is polluted with `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast(topic, type, data)`. This broadcast is triggered by some external source events (in my case it’s RabbitMQ.)

The scenario is: MQ client receives a message ⇒ the application broadcasts it to all subscribers of the specific channel. I use the native local RabbitMQ server in tests.

How would I test it? [`Phoenix.ChannelTest.assert_broadcast/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ChannelTest.html#assert_broadcast/3) does not work saying *“The process mailbox is empty.”*.

`assert_reply` requires a reference and being called as `assert_reply Phoenix.Channel.socket_ref(socket), ...` is not working as well, raising *“(ArgumentError) Socket refs can only be generated for a socket that has joined with a push ref”.*

I am positive the broadcast is indeed triggering (checked in both `dev` and `test` environments with [`wsta`](https://github.com/esphen/wsta).)

So, my question would be: **how do I test the broadcast event triggered by some external source within Phoenix test suite?**

---

When I have tried to subscribe to the respective channel from test process, as suggested by @Kociamber, it fails the same way with *“The process mailbox is empty.”*,

```
test "handle RabbitMQ message", %{socket: _socket} do
  Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe MyApp.PubSub, "channel:topic"
  payload = %{foo: "bar"}
  RabbitMQ.trigger!(payload)
  assert_receive ^payload, 3_000
end
```

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried increasing the timeout of `assert_broadcast`?

Comment: @Dogbert sure, it’s `5_000` now :) That was my first attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found following way useful for channel (and broadcast) testing, it looks like it should work for you as well. First you need to subscribe to your topic with [`Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#subscribe/2), define your expected message (payload) value and then use [`assert_receive/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html#assert_receive/3) to test against it:

```
assert_receive ^expected_payload
```

You may also want to unsubscribe from the topic after your test is done with [`Phoenix.PubSub.unsubscribe/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#unsubscribe/2)

Comment: After all: this is a perfect solution, and I am goofy :) I messed up with topic names and that’s the only reason it did not work.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Indeed, wrong topic was the only thing I could think of ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the test for broadcasting message to channel members this might help you

```
 test "new_msg event broadcasts new message to other channel members",
  %{socket1: socket1, user1: user1, group: group} do
     {:ok, _, socket1} = subscribe_and_join(socket1, "groups:#
    {group.slug}")

   @endpoint.subscribe("groups:#{group.slug}")

   ref = push socket1, "new_msg", %{text_content: "Hello, World!"}
   assert_reply ref, :ok

   assert_broadcast "new_msg", data

   assert data.user_id == user1.id
   assert data.text_content == "Hello, World!"
 end
```